# How to serialize an array like an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects, associative-array

If I create an associative array like this:

```
var a = []; 
a.push("hello");
a["hello"] = "world";
JSON.stringify(a);
```

and serialize it as JSON, the result is

> "["hello"]"

If I create it like

```
var a = {};
a["hello"] = "world";
JSON.stringify(a);
```

the result is

> "{"hello":"world"}"

Is there a way in JavaScript to serialize the array variant like the object variant ? 
I mean without copying all properties into an object, and without writing an own JSON-stringifier ?

Comment: `a["hello"] = "world";` doesn't change the array at all, it seems. Try changing it to `a["test"] = "world";` and see that the JSON remains unchanged.

Comment: What do you expect `a["hello"] = "world";` to do when `a` is an array?

Comment: @Henrik `a` is still an object, and the `"hello"` key is added to it, but the serializer still treats `a` as an array. I'm wondering why would OP use the array as such

Comment: in short, no. because there is no possibility to create an array literal with properties.

Comment: There is no "associative array" in JavaScript. Its either an object `{}` (with key value pairs) or an array `[]` with numeric indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only looking to `stringify` those properties which you have **either pushed (`a.push("hello");`) or assigned (like `a["hello"] = "world";`) programmatically**, then you can use `Object.assign`

```
JSON.stringify( Object.assign ( {}, a ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var a = []; 
a.push("hello");
a["hello"] = "world";
console.log(JSON.stringify( Object.assign ( {}, a ) ));
```

Comment: you are loosing the array parts, like `length` and the prototypes.

Comment: @NinaScholz Looks like OP is only looking to Stringify the properties which are either pushed or assigned. I will point out the same in answer anyways.

Comment: @gurvinder372: Correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the array part and the part without the array part and reassemble after stringifying the whole object together for a new array with custom properties.

```js
var a = []; 

a.push("hello");
a["hello"] = "world";

var o = Object.assign(...Object.keys(a).map(k => (+k).toString() !== k ? { [k]: a[k] } : {})),
    jsonArray = JSON.stringify(a),
    jsonObject = JSON.stringify(o);
    
console.log(a);
console.log(jsonArray);
console.log(o);
console.log(jsonObject);

var combined = Object.assign(JSON.parse(jsonArray), JSON.parse(jsonObject));

console.log(Array.isArray(combined));
console.log(combined);
console.log(Object.keys(combined).map(k => [k, combined[k]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that is not possible (maybe I'm wrong), but when you do `a.push('hello')` you're assigning the value `hello` to the first index of the `array`.

```
console.log(a)
Array(
  0: "hello"
)
```

Then, when you do `a["hello"] = "world"`what you're doing here is adding an index with the name `hello` and assigning it the value of `world`.

If you log it you get:

```
Array (
  0: "hello",
  "hello": "world"
)
```